# How long will food stay hot in The Long Dark?

Tags: the-long-dark

I have cooked Pinnacle Peaches. How soon must I eat them before they will no longer provide the bonus for being hot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Food seems to remain hot for 100 in-game minutes** (8 minutes and 30 seconds in real time).

I cooked a can of Pinnacle Peaches, then cooked other items while frequently checking the status of the cooked peaches in my inventory. The peaches kept the **Hot** status until 100 minutes had passed in the game, at which point they became **Cold**.

I was standing indoors next to a fire for the entire time. I do not know whether colder ambient temperature would have an effect on the food.

Update: The behavior does seem to vary, probably by ambient temperature. I attempted to let hot soup sit on an outdoor fire barrel for 1 hour while I slept, and the food was cold when I awoke. I reloaded the save and tried to sleep outdoors with hot food in my inventory, and it was cold when I awoke.